# Angular 4 Page Scroll to Anchor

Tags: angular, animation

I'm trying to make the page scroll to an anchor when a certain button is clicked in ANGULAR 4, for Angular 2 there are packages on npm, but i have no idea how to do it on 4?

Scroll for Angular 2
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-page-scroll

Comment: Use that package, it has a dependency of angular (versio:n ^4.0.2), don't get irritated by the name. Due to many devs initially named their libraries `ng2-*` and now everyone starts to change it to `ngx-*` (cause due to naming conventions there is just `angular` and no such thing as `angular2`).